# Gather all elements of a list defined by a list of ranges

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to do the following:

I have a list, say:

```
a = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4},{5},{6}}
```

and a list which specifies the range:

```
range = {{1, 3}, {4, 6}};
```

Now I would like to receive a list, which gathers elementwise all list elements of list `a` within the range of "range".

The result should be:

```
result = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

What I tried:

```
t = {};
result = AppendTo[t, a[[#[[1]], #[[2]] ]] ] & /@ a
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Although not answering your specific question,  `TakeDrop` might be worth considering?  `TakeDrop[Flatten@a, 3]` or `TakeDrop[Flatten@a, First@range]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
Flatten[Take[a, #]] & /@ range
```

> {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}

Answer (score 7):

```
result = Range @@@ range
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}

Or more like your own code:

```
a = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}};
range = {{1, 3}, {4, 6}};
t = {};
result = Last[AppendTo[t, a[[#[[1]] ;; #[[2]], 1]]] & /@ range]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Why are you not using a in the first solution ?

Comment: How would you do it, if a would be: a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} ?

Comment: @totyped For `a = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}` you want the output `{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}` and for `a =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` i don't understand how the output should change. What should output be?

Comment: The output should be the same.

Comment: @totyped That's why i don't use `a` in the first one. I the second you would need to remove `, 1`

Answer (score 5):

```
a = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}} // Flatten;

range = {{1, 3}, {4, 6}};

Pick[a, #] & /@ Outer[IntervalMemberQ[Interval[#1], #2] &,
  range, a, 1]

(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

I may be missing the point here, but it seems to me that there is some ambiguity in what constitutes a generalization of the question, and the answers posted appear to be generalizing in quite different ways and/or answering quite different questions.

This ambiguity stems from the nice sequential ordering of `a` and `range`, but one interpretation (possibly just mine) of the requirement

> "I would like to receive a list, which gathers elementwise all list elements of list a within the range of `range`"

can be better illustrated by the following less nice example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
a = Sort@RandomSample[List /@ Range[20], 10]
range = {{1, #}, {# + 1, 20}} &@ RandomInteger[{Min[a] + 1, Max[a] - 2}]

(* {{1}, {2}, {6}, {8}, {9}, {11}, {13}, {16}, {17}, {19}} *)

(* {{1, 5}, {6, 20}} *)
```

The "correct" output (again, according to me, and possibly not to the OP) should be

```
(* {{1, 2}, {6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19}} *)
```

which (as far as I can tell) only @Nasser's `Map` and @BobHanlon's `Pick` provide. (Obviously, this is still "nice" to some extent -- I'm assuming `a` is an ordered list of integers, `range` is composed of only two intervals, etc..)

Here's an assortment of other functions which provide the "correct" answer:

```
Pick[Flatten[a], UnitStep[Flatten[a] - range[[2, 1]]], #] & /@ {0, 1}

TakeDrop[#, First@FirstPosition[#, x_ /; x > range[[1, 2]]] - 1] &@ Flatten[a]

GatherBy[Flatten[a], # <= range[[1, 2]] &]

Last@Reap[Scan[Sow[#, # <= range[[1, 2]]] &, Flatten[a]]]
```

(They also give the right output for the example in the question.)

Comment: Indeed, I open a question and see instead of vtc because unclear, lots of answers, yet I am completely baffled as to op's actual intent. Why must `a` be a nested list, for example?

Answer (score 4):

```
Flatten[a[[Span @@ #]]] & /@ range
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}

or

```
Extract[a, List /@ (Range @@@ range), Flatten]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}

Further examples:

```
Extract[Range[0, 100, 10], List /@ (Range @@@ range), Flatten]
```

> {{0, 10, 20}, {30, 40, 50}}

```
Extract[CharacterRange["A","Z"], List /@ (Range @@@ range), Flatten]
```

> {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"D", "E", "F"}}

Answer (score 4):

Using `Intersection`

```
a = Flatten@{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}};
range = Range @@@ {{1, 3}, {4, 6}};
```

And now

```
Map[Intersection[a, #] &, range]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lets say your data now becomes

```
a = Flatten@{{1}, {2}, {5}, {6}};
```

Then

```
Map[Intersection[a, #] &, range]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]